# 1" inch pipe connected to 3/4" pipe at meter outlet

Tags: plumbing

The meter outlet at the street has a 3/4 check valve.

If i am connecting 1 inch pipe to the check or back flow valve, what are the effects on flow and pressure ?

Comment: Meter for what ?  What are  you talking about ?  "*what are the effects on flow and pressure*"   Flow and pressure  of what  ?  **Much more info is needed**.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Putting in 1” will reduce pressure losses especially important with long distances from the meter to the house static pressure will not be affected . In my state 3/4 is the minimum size and 1” is recommended up to the water heater split if there is no pressure reducing valve. if You want other information, you could ask it by editing the question.

Comment: Tagging to add those thought: you can't do any harm AFAIK for installing the larger pipe

Comment: the water meter outlet is one inch  - the check valve is one inch going in but 3/4 going out-  I will add a 3/4 to 1 inch adapter and continue on with 1 inch pipe  for a 100 ft run - hopefully to increase water flow efficiency